# asdf python not installing properly on mac sonoma

Tags: python-3.x, asdf-vm, macos-sonoma

I followed the asdf instructions to install python and its not working properly.
I installed python version 3.11.6 and 3.12.0.
When I run the command asdf global python 3.11.6 it does nothing.
If I run python in the command I get command not found.
If I run python3 it starts a python 3.6.12 session.
When I go to my dev directory and run asdf local python 3.12.0 it works but nothing finds the version of python.

The terminal session in VS code doesn't work but I was able to get it to find the interpreter.

Because python is not set properly I can't setup venv inside my project either.

This is a brand new mac, installed homebrew then asdf.

No idea what is going on.

Please help

Answer (score 0):

I had to follow the zsh steps from homebrew install.
I was following the macOS instructions.